# In ASP.NET, why does DbSet.LastAsync() not exist?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-web-api, async-await, entity-framework-6

I've make some codes implementing some web API.
This API method returns last record of Foo Table.

```
public class FooController : ApiController
{
    private FooContext db = new FooContext();

    // GET: api/Foo
    [ResponseType(typeof(Foo))]
    public async Task<IHttpActionResult> GetLastFoo()
    {
        Foo foo = await db.Foo.Last();
        if (foo == null)
        {
            return NotFound();
        }
        return Ok(foo);
    }
}
```

I want make this API asynchronous, but there is no LastAsync() method.
Why and how can I solve it?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should not use Task.Run in ASP.NET:

> Async and await on ASP.NET are all about I/O. They really excel at
>   reading and writing files, database records, and REST APIs. However,
>   they’re not good for CPU-bound tasks. You can kick off some background
>   work by awaiting Task.Run, but there’s no point in doing so. In fact,
>   that will actually hurt your scalability by interfering with the
>   ASP.NET thread pool heuristics. If you have CPU-bound work to do on
>   ASP.NET, your best bet is to just execute it directly on the request
>   thread. As a general rule, don’t queue work to the thread pool on
>   ASP.NET.

From [Async Programming : Introduction to Async/Await on ASP.NET](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dn802603.aspx)

Still it does not mean you can't use async and await in ASP.NET for I/O (and that's what you want) just use real async methods and not a fake async wrappers over synchronous methods (that will just push the work into other ThreadPool thread and you will [not gain any performance benfit from it](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33764670/6248956)).

Since you don't have LastAsync method in EF I suggest you to use OrderBy to order your collection as you want and to use [FirstAsync](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.queryableextensions.firstasync(v=vs.113).aspx#M:System.Data.Entity.QueryableExtensions.FirstAsync%60%601(System.Linq.IQueryable%7B%60%600%7D)) method (or FirstAsync overload that supports lambda predicate) instead of using Last method, FirstAsync is a true async I/O method that is supported in EF.

More info about when it's appropriate to use Task.Run can be found in [Task.Run Etiquette Examples: Don't Use Task.Run in the Implementation](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/11/taskrun-etiquette-examples-dont-use.html) article in Stephen Cleary's blog.

Your question why there is no LastAsync method in the first place should be directed to the team at Microsoft that desiged EF api, but my guess is that they didn't bother implementing it since it is so easy to achieve the same functionally with FirstAsync method as I suggested.

Answer (score 0):

A working version of that code would look like this:

```
    public class FooController : ApiController
{
    private FooContext db = new FooContext();

    // GET: api/Foo
    [ResponseType(typeof(Foo))]
    public async Task<IHttpActionResult> GetLastFoo()
    {
        Foo foo = await db.Foo.OrderByDesc(x=> x.Timestamp).FirstOrDefaultAsync(); 
        if (foo == null)
        {
            return NotFound();
        }
        return Ok(foo);
    }
}
```

Last etc don't work against an EF IQueryable because SQL doesn't have an equivalent command

Answer (score -5):

about how to solve it

you can use

```
 await Task.Run(()=>db.Foo.Last());
```

Comment: But you shouldn't in ASP.NET. It will just eat resources and perform worst.

Comment: You should absotlutely not do this. ths will burn ressources for nothing. There is no benefit to this .