# Task.Run() in async method causes thread pool starvation?

Tags: c#, .net-core, async-await

I have this piece of code in my .netcore application

```
[HttpPost]
[Route("doSomething")]
public async Task<IActionResult> DoSomethingAsync([FromBody] Input input)
{
    // Do Something
    var task1 = Task.Run(async () => 
    {
        await taskFactory.DoTask(input);
    });

    // Do Something Differently
    var task2 = Task.Run(async () => 
    {
        await taskFactory.DoAnotherTask(input);
    });

    await Task.WhenAll(task1, task2);

    return Accepted();
}
```

`DoTask()` and `DoAnotherTask()` are both independent of each other and can be executed in parallel but they have to be awaited until both of them are in completed status.

So, I created two tasks and awaited them using `Task.WhenAll()`.

But I have got a review comment to not use `Task.Run()` in an `async` method as it can lead to thread pool starvation.

Question 1: How does my code leading to thread pool starvation?
Question 2: If it is leading to thread pool starvation, how can I run both tasks in parallel?

Comment: Why are you doing `Task.Run` here instead of just returning the task from `DoTask`?

Comment: Also, how have you diagnosed that ThreadPool starvation is your issue?

Comment: Note how you don't `await` the result from `Task.Run` and instead capture the task to use in a `Task.WhenAll` you can also just do the same for the results from `DoTask` and `DoAnotherTask` instead.

Comment: @DavidG Yes, that can be avoided. It is unnecessary. But just want  to understand how will it lead to thread pool starvation.

Comment: The only reason to wrap these calls in `Task.Run` is if they have CPU bound code up front before they get to whatever `async` code they are doing.

Comment: The thread pool has a finite number of available threads. `Task.Run` queues work to run on the thread pool, so it's possible to use up all the threads, if it is over used.

Comment: @JohnathanBarclay juharr Thanks, that's what I wanted to know.

Comment: @juharr JohnathanBarclay you can consolidate you statements. I have got the answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To answer your question with confidence we must know the implementation of the `DoTask` and `DoAnotherTask` methods. Without knowing it we could just assume that they are implemented properly and follow the etiquette for async methods, which is to return a `Task` immediately, without blocking the calling thread. Under this assumption, the answer is: **No, your code doesn't lead to thread pool starvation.** This is because the [`ThreadPool`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.threadpool) thread employed by [`Task.Run`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task.run) has a negligible amount of work to do, which is just to create a `Task` object, so it will be returned back to the `ThreadPool` almost immediately.

It should be pointed out that although wrapping well behaved async delegates with `Task.Run` has negligible impact to the health of the `ThreadPool`, it offers no benefit either. Take a look at this semi-related question: [Is Task.Run considered bad practice in an ASP .NET MVC Web Application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33764366/is-task-run-considered-bad-practice-in-an-asp-net-mvc-web-application)

Answer (score 2):

For your thread pool starvation question, if you run a task, which is already async, executes 2 new Tasks, with task.run and inside that you run 2 async methods you have per call 5 Tasks, then you await the completion of both and you are at 6 Tasks per Request.

I usually do smth like this, you still have 4 Tasks, but in the end the pool would last longer.

```
[HttpPost]
[Route("doSomething")]
public async Task<IActionResult> DoSomethingAsync([FromBody] Input input)
{
    // Do Something
    var t1 = taskFactory.DoTask(input);

    // Do Something Differently
    var t2 = taskFactory.DoAnotherTask(input);


    await Task.WhenAll(t1, t2);

    return Accepted();
}
```

Comment: That may be a better way to do it, but doesnt answer the OP question regarding whether  thread pool starvation is at risk like his code reviewer told them it was.